# setting an environment variable for a specific MPI process

Tags: fortran, environment-variables, mpi

I am running a Fortran code in MPI.  I need to set an environment variable in one particular process.  Is there a way to do this?  Calling "system" from the Fortran code does not seem to have an effect.  I am running the code via "aprun".

Comment: In mpirun or during the run?

Comment: @Vladimir F  As long as it "sticks" I would be satisfied either way.  I think I would like to do it from mpirun (aprun, actually) because that seems to be more certain to give me what I want.

Comment: You can do MPMD-like launch where you use the same binary but different opts. Your Cray supercomputing center can help you if necessary.

Comment: I agree with Jeff. Be aware you must use a separate node on a Cray for a separate MPMD job.

Comment: @VladimirF Good point, but is that limitation present when the binary is the same?

Comment: @Jeff As far as I tried yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Launcher solution

You should do this with MPMD launching.  It works with `mpirun` or `aprun`.

Here is an example, where one sets the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable differently on one process than the others.

```
aprun -n 1  -e OMP_NUM_THREADS=1  ./mpi-openmp-app.x input_file.in :
      -n 99 -e OMP_NUM_THREADS=10 ./mpi-openmp-app.x input_file.in
```

This is the heterogeneous equivalent of

```
aprun -n 100 -e OMP_NUM_THREADS=10 ./mpi-openmp-app.x input_file.in
```

Please see the [aprun man page](http://docs.cray.com/cgi-bin/craydoc.cgi?mode=Show;q=;f=man/alpsm/10/cat1/aprun.1.html) (or `man aprun` from the command line) for details.

Note that Cray is in the process of switching many sites from ALPS (i.e. `aprun`) to SLURM (`srun`), but I'm sure that SLURM supports the same feature.

MPI's `mpirun` or `mpiexec` supports a similar feature.  The syntax is not specified by the MPI standard, so you need to read the documentation of your MPI implementation for the specifics.

## Source code solution

Assuming your environment variable is parsed after MPI is initialized, you can do something like the following using [`setenv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html), if the launcher solution does not work.

```
int requested=MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED, provided;
MPI_Init_thread(&argc,&argv,requested,&provided);

int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
if (rank==0) {
  int overwrite = 1;
  int rc = setenv("OMP_NUM_THREADS","1",overwrite);
}
```

Comment: In the launcher solution, is there a way to specify the process that gets the environment variable?  Thanks!

Comment: I would expect the processes are numbered in the order they are launched, unless you enable rank reordering.

Comment: I tried the launcher solution on a Cray system and it seems the second binary is not able to identify the env variable. ALPS gives a unidentified "aprun: invalid option -- 'e'" error.

Comment: I did test it. Might be syntax error. Can you try with 2 processes on 2 nodes though.