# Setting Different OMP_NUM_THREADS Value per Node in Distributed MPI Job

Tags: mpi, openmp, distributed-computing, openmpi

I can run an MPI job this way:

```
mpirun --hostfile Hostfile -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out
```

Where the `Hostfile` contains:

```
node1 slots=2 
node2 slots=2
```

This currently sets `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` in all of the nodes. But what if I want to do something like this?

```
node1 slots=2, OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 
node2 slots=2, OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
```

Regardless if this is recommended or not. Is possible to do it? If yes, how? Thank you.

Comment: Set the thread count in your code, based on process number.

Comment: That, or simply write a wrapper.

Comment: Did you try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34953091/7212665 ? It simply  `mpirun -np 1 --env VAR=3 ./my_prog : -np 1 --env VAR=5 ./my_prog`